# Postman if statement goes ininite loop

Tags: loops, infinite-loop

```
    let coderepoarr = pm.collectionVariables.get("coderepoarr")
let i = 0
console.log(coderepoarr.length)
 if ( i< coderepoarr.length  && pm.response.to.have.status(200) ) {
        let firstElement = pm.collectionVariables.get("firstElement")
        firstElement++
        postman.setNextRequest("commit all CR")
        pm.collectionVariables.set("firstElement", firstElement)
        i++
        console.log(firstElement)
   
    } else{
        postman.setNextRequest(null);
    }
```

Im trying this but always I'm getting infite loop, can someone help>?